# HTML5 Viewer duplicates image mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-plugins

I have an HTML5 viewer that is loading images.

```
 <div id="Frame" class="animateCreatorContainer" style="width:@ViewBag.ImgWidthHTML5Viewer; height:@ViewBag.ImgHeightHTML5Viewer; margin-left:1px; margin-top:1px;"></div>
    <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $('#Frame').animate360({
                                    centerInWindow: false, // if switch to true it will center the image
                                    xmlPath: '@Url.Content("~/img/HTML/" + @ViewBag.PartNumber + "/")',
                                    objPath: '@Url.Content("~/img/HTML/" + @ViewBag.PartNumber + "/Images/")',
                                    iconPath: '@Url.Content("~/img/HTML/HTML5/Images/")',
                                });                                  
                            });
    </script>
```

When this get rendered I get two pictures on the page. 
One is smaller and one is bigger.

[Generated Code in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2hFz.png)

[Duplicate plus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M7dg.png)

Am I missing something from the plug-in settings to disable the dual image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, you're including this as a partial and loading that partial multiple times, which means you're then duplicating the JavaScript code and causing it to run multiple times, duplicating the chrome like the zoom-in icon, etc.

If this isn't in a partial being loaded multiple times, I'd still wager on the JavaScript being include multiple times. Perhaps you have this JavaScript already in your layout, for example.

Assuming this is the case, you have two options, though you should probably actually do both, even though either one alone should be enough to fix it:

1. Make sure each instance has a unique `id` attribute and then have this bit of JavaScript target that particular unique id. For example, assuming this is a partial, you could do something like:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("MyPartial", someModel, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
   {
       { "id", "Frame1" }
   });
   ```

   Then, in your partial:

   ```
   <div id="@ViewData["id"]" ...>
       ...
       $('@ViewData["id"]').animate360({
   ```
2. Just move the script out of the partial and into your layout, so it's only ever ran once. Then, use a class instead of an id to attach the plugin:

   ```
   <div class="frame" ...>
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   $('.frame').animate360({
   ```

Comment: You are right. I was loading this with a partial view and the the Java Script Code loaded up from within the partial view and I had forgotten about the original JS code on the page thus creating the double image.